# Cookie without Identity Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a project that I don't use Identity.

The things is that this project should have a remember me option that allow user to automatically reconnect into the web site.

My problem is that I can't find any complete tutoriel to create a cookie without Identity.

If somebody have a good sample of code or tutoial :)

Thanks

Comment: Write a cookie: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547(v=vs.71).aspx Read a cookie: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287533(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have a simple cookie auth solution sample here https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth

Answer (score 3):

In my project, I use AngularJS for Frontend and  .Net Core API for Backend.
So, I don't need to configure pages for `AccessDeniedPath`, `LoginPath` and so on.

Here's what I do:

- Configure the cookie in the startup class:

  ```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    //...
    CookieAuthenticationOptions options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie";
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.CookieName = "MyCookie";
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options);
    //...
  }
  ```
- The login is like this:

  ```
  [HttpPost, Route("Login")]
  public IActionResult LogIn([FromBody]LoginModel login) {
    //...
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("MyCookie");
    //add the login as the name of the user
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, login.Login));
    //add a list of roles
    foreach (Role r in someList.Roles) {
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name));
    }
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookie", principal).Wait();
    return Ok();
  }
  ```
- The logout is like this:

  ```
  [HttpPost, Route("Logout")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut() {
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookie");
    return Ok();
  }
  ```
- Then you can use it like this:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize(Roles = "Role1,Role2,Role3")]
  public IActionResult Post() {
    //...
    string userName = this.User.Identity.Name;
    //...
  }
  ```

*See that the method is authorized only for "Role1, Role2 and Role3". And see how to get the user name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to make a persistent cookie when the user logs in with a "Remember Me?" checkbox selected.

All the answers are on the right path - you'll ultimately invoke `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync`, but the cookie middleware issues a session cookie by default. You'll need to pass along authentication properties as a third parameter to make the cookie persistent, for example:

```
HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(
     Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme,
     userPrincipal,
     new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good article on this here: [Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie).

Basically what you do is set up the cookie handling middleware *as if* you were going to identify the user, but then you just create a ClaimsPrincipal object without asking the user to login. You pass that object to the SigninAsync method and it creates the cookie for you. If you follow this article you should be fine.

Comment: I already follow the documentation article, for me is not why I expect from setting a basic cookie with one or two values to reconnect the user.

Comment: Yes, it does _seem_ a bit complicated but I think if you implemented everything yourself you'd end up with something similar. You still have access to cookies via HttpContext.Response.Cookies. If you take a peak inside an action in an MVC controller using Intellisense you'll see it there. But you want the information on every request so you need to create some sort of middleware that you put at the front of the pipeline to access the context and manage the cookie before it gets to any of your controllers. So you'll end up writing some sort of middleware component like the one in the article.