# What is an easy but safe way for authentication in .net core webapi?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I looked into Identityserver4 but I think this is too much overhead for me because I don't need things like implicit authentication and the ability of asking users if they want to allow that application to access their account.

The usermanagement should be done in my application that will use the api. So I think a simple token based authentication will do (or am I wrong?). And what kind of library should I use for this?

Is it possible to use asp.net core identity with an asp.net core webapi (if so, is this a good way?)?

Comment: I personally use JWT nowadays, combined with a database or a simple text file - it depends on the project.

Comment: You can also use cookies. Take a look in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935872/cookie-without-identity-asp-net-core/40938859#40938859).

Comment: Check out [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) in combination with ASP.NET Core Identity. If you want a hosted solution, [Stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/#tab2) might work for you.

Comment: @NateBarbettini thanks for the tip! It looks a lot more simpler than identityserver4.